# Present perfect continuous for both actions which are still happening and actions which have just finished

Tags: grammar

I know that present perfect continuous can be used for actions which have just finished, or are still happening at the moment of speaking.

I would like to know that if my these 2 sentences below are correct or not:

> (1) People **have been going** to the park to do morning exercises
> recently.
> ( on the news report- the trend is currently happening now).
>
> (2) People **have been going** to the park to do morning exercises
> recently, but since the news of there being a ghost in the part, the
> part has become empty.
> (the trend has just stopped)

Comment: "People **had been going** to the park... **until** recently, but..."